# CodeIgniter shows "ArgumentCountError" even though I have passed the arguments

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to auto fill some fields from a table and save those inputs into another table using CodeIgniter 3. Auto fill part works fine but when I try to submit, it gives "ArgumentCountError". It says 0 passed but as my knowledge I have already passed a argument. I'm new to CodeIgniter so please help me to fix this issue.

Error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function Staff::donate(), 0 passed in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\blood\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Filename: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\blood\application\controllers\Staff.php

Line Number: 70

Backtrace:

File: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\blood\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

View:

```
<?php echo form_open('staff/savepacket/' . $donor->DonorID); ?>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Donor Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1"
               name="donorname" value="<?php echo $donor->DonorName ?>" readonly>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Donor NIC</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1"
               name="donornic" value="<?php echo $donor->DonorNIC ?>" readonly>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Donor ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1"
               name="donorid" value="<?php echo $donor->DonorID ?>" readonly>
    </div>


    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Donated Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="packetdonateddate">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Comments</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="comments"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="control ">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
        ">Save</button>
    </div>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function donate($donor) {
        $this->load->model('Donor_Model');
        $data['donor'] = $this->Donor_Model->donate($donor);
        $this->load->view('packetregister', $data);
    }

    public function savePacket($packet) {
        $donatedDate = $this->input->post('packetdonateddate');
        $expiringDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($donatedDate. ' + 42 days'));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('packetdonateddate', 'Donated Date', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data = [
                'DonorID' => $this->input->post('donorid'),
                'DonatedDate' => $this->input->post('packetdonateddate'),
                'ExpiringDate' => $expiringDate,
                'comments' => $this->input->post('comments'),
            ];
            $this->load->model('Donor_Model');
            $data['donor'] = $this->Donor_Model->savePacket($data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('packetsaved', 'Donation successful!');
            redirect(base_url('index.php/staff/donate'));
        } else {
            $this->donate($packet);
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
function donate($donor) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('donors', array('DonorID' => $donor));
        return $query->row();
    }

    function savePacket($data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert('packets', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Print and see $donor have some value when called thru http

Comment: You are missing index.php which is calling Donor, and is calling it wrong.  BTW using the same controller function name and model function name (For a different model) REALLY makes it hard to read.

Comment: dump `$donor` value in model and before calling to `donate` function.